# How to increase the thickness of the plane geometry in threejs

Tags: three.js

Here I'm trying to increase the thickness of the plane geometry, where when I try to rotate the plane geometry to a specific direction the geometry is getting hide. I'm trying to create a geometry like the last image where i planed to create two plane geometry and overlap that to the positions and remove the texture color of the geometry and to add border thickness to the geometry. Will that works!

1. Give thickness to the plane geometry
2. How to design the shape like the image given below

Kindly, help me out with the issue

I have attached the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e1ca7pwj/1/

```
var cube = document.querySelector('.cube');

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true
    });
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff0);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));
    scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(5));

    var geom = new THREE.CircleGeometry(5, 32);
    var mats = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00 });

    var box = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mats);
    scene.add(box);

    var mat = new THREE.Matrix4();

    renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {

        mat.extractRotation(camera.matrixWorldInverse);

        cube.style.transform = `translateZ(-300px) ${getCameraCSSMatrix(mat)}`;

        renderer.render(scene, camera);

    });

    function getCameraCSSMatrix(matrix) {

        var elements = matrix.elements;

        return 'matrix3d(' +
            epsilon(elements[0]) + ',' +
            epsilon(-elements[1]) + ',' +
            epsilon(elements[2]) + ',' +
            epsilon(elements[3]) + ',' +
            epsilon(elements[4]) + ',' +
            epsilon(-elements[5]) + ',' +
            epsilon(elements[6]) + ',' +
            epsilon(elements[7]) + ',' +
            epsilon(elements[8]) + ',' +
            epsilon(-elements[9]) + ',' +
            epsilon(elements[10]) + ',' +
            epsilon(elements[11]) + ',' +
            epsilon(elements[12]) + ',' +
            epsilon(-elements[13]) + ',' +
            epsilon(elements[14]) + ',' +
            epsilon(elements[15]) +
            ')';

    }

    function epsilon(value) {

        return Math.abs(value) < 1e-10 ? 0 : value;

    }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
 [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CircleGeometry` is similar to `PlaneGeometry` always flat. Their vertices are generated in the XY plane without depth. Meaning the z-component of all vertices is `0`.

If you need a geometry with a volume, I suggest you use `CylinderGeometry` or `BoxGeometry` instead.

`three.js R112`

Comment: Planar elements without depth like a circle has 2 sides right, so, irrespective of depth, the other side should also be visible right? Maybe issue is with the code implementation?

Comment: @lifetimeLearner007 I have forget to add texture to the backside of the material and that's the reason